# Async REST API calls using requests in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Can anyone please help me in writting a code in python to make async rest api call using request module

Currently I am using `urllib2`

```
import urllib2
urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

I need to make the call after reading a file,create this api based on the value in  the file. The file has more than 2 million lines, so finally I need to invoke 2 million rest api calls. How do I invoke this with best performance, very short time, like in 1 minute.

Comment: 2 million API calls will take a little longer than 1 minute..

Comment: Can you please  mention how to make the calls using requests

Comment: For this task ,I am using celery-rabbit mq.After reading each line of from my csv ,I create the api url's and then pass it to my tasks in task module.

Comment: from celery import Celery
import urllib2,requests
celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@celery.task
def add(url):
    urllib2.urlopen(url)
    #requests.post(url)

Comment: How can I make the def add(url) to execute very fast..These url and REST api calls and I dont need any response .Can you please help me .I am very new to Python and this is an important task given